# How to change form id after deleting dynamically?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm generating a dynamic form in JavaScript and when I delete a form by id I don't know how to set ids in order 1,2,3... you can view my code on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wdLtv01x/1/

```
if (document.getElementById(childDiv))
{
    var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    i--;    
}
```

and sorry for my bad English.

THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `i--;` in your `removeElement` function, this works fine I think.

```
window.removeElement = function(parentDiv, childDiv){

    if (document.getElementById(childDiv)){
        var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        i--;
        //decrement();    
    }
};
```

**Update after comments :**

I added a class for each created form then I loop in all elements which have this class and update the form number.

```
var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('interview-form');
console.log(forms);
for(var j = 0; j < forms.length; j++){
    console.log(forms[j].getElementsByTagName('h2'));
    forms[j].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'Interview '+ (j+2);
}
```

The fiddle is updated (but I just did it for the H2 element). Drop a comment if you have more questions.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdLtv01x/6/)

Comment: if i create 3 form and i delete the seconde one i have interview1 and interview3, and i need to have interview1 , interview2

Comment: Oh okay, didn't understand it like this, I'll take a look

Comment: Thank you !! Sorry, I wasn't clear enough with my question !!

Comment: Not problem ! I Updated my answer

Comment: Merci beaucoup Mteuahasan !!! it works perfectly

Comment: Petit probléme !! when I add a form sometimes it duplicates the form 
Interview 1

Comment: Well...this is weird, this problem doesn't appear on my fiddle ! Could you fiddle me this ?

Comment: It was not related to u're code sorry !! -_-' I duplicated an id on my form stupid me !! Sorry and thanks again

Comment: It happens ! Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Since you add jQuery on your fiddle, so I use jQuery because it's more concise.

First, for easier selection I add class `interview` to every divs. Then when you remove a div, try to save the index of removed div. Finally, decrement the value of all div which has index >= the removed index.

```
window.removeElement = function(parentDiv, childDiv){

    if (document.getElementById(childDiv)){
        var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);

        //save the index of removed element
        var removed_index = Number(childDiv.split("_")[1]);

        //add class interview to all divs
        $(".interview").each(function(index){
            if(index + 1 >= removed_index){
                //if true, change the title and id
                $(this).find("h2").text("Interview "+(index+1));
                $(this).attr("id", "id_"+(index + 1));
                $(this).find("button").attr("onclick", "removeElement('myCandidat','id_"+(index + 1)+"')");
            }
        });
        i--;
        //decrement();    
    }
};
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdLtv01x/7/) for further testing..

Comment: Thanks for the solution  :D ! but when I try to delete the second form it do not work ??

Comment: I forgot to rename the string on `onclick` function.. Already edited the code and fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly !!